Operator systems in functional analysis & quantum mechanics: intuition
I saw this concept of operator systems in here but I am not sure if I want to get deep into it before knowing roughly what it is used for in, say, quantum information or quantum mechanics.
My very limited understanding is that an operator system $\mathcal{S}$ is very much like the $C^{*}$ algebras used to describe algebras of observables in quantum mechanics, except that you remove the algebra products (i.e., we do not allow $AB\in\mathcal{S}$ whenever $A,B\in\mathcal{S}$) while keeping all other properties (like $A^* \in \mathcal{S}$ whenever $A\in\mathcal{S}$, as well as closed under sum of operators).
At the core, my question is:

Is operator system enough to do quantum mechanics, or do I need to use a full $C^*$ algebra and then use GNS representation to get the von Neumann algebras and Hilbert space?

For example, does GNS representation work in operator systems and do they give something sensible? I am not sure if I should ask this in Mathematics Stackexchange because the only context I care about is in quantum mechanics, yet at the same time this is in functional analysis territory.

Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Actually I don't know if my answer can be satisfactory, in particular as I cannot freely access the source you refer to. May be the developed functional analysis (FA) in that book fits well to Quantum Information Theory.
But the post also mentions Quantum mechanics (QM) and the concept intuition. I think, I can say something with respect to that. Actually, there a many users on physics stackexchange who have a better knowledge in the application of FA to QM, so my contribution can give only a glimpse on the topic.
The commutation rule of the momentum and position operator are in the heart of Quantum mechanics, which makes it so extraordinary:
$$[x,p] = i\hbar$$
Both operators are actually very difficult to treat in FA, they are unbounded operators which in the sense of FA even do not have neither  eigenfunctions nor eigenvalues in a reasonable Hilbert space.
Whereas in QM that is not a problem, both operators are considered to have eigenfunctions and eigenvalues, only they are not part of a classical Hilbert space (well there exists a concept like a rigged Hilbert space, possibly in such a space eigenfunctions of the momentum operators could be defined).
So in order to make QM mathematically sound, one has to delve very deeply into FA, much more than standard textbooks on FA offer and develop special concepts which could make QM mathematically sound. There are even concepts (Feynman's path integral for instance, but very trendy at the moment) which still have not found a rigorous mathematical foundation.
May be the reference which is mentioned does this for Quantum information theory. I am writing this in order to provide the intuition for the intricate relationship of Functional analysis and Quantum mechanics.
Briefly, physicists above all care about the physical concepts, mathematical rigor is only secondary. The answer to the question asked "Is operator system enough to do QM": probably not.
